# Please help clarify this CodeIgniter example (calling a method within itself)

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

Looking at [**the example found here in the Codeigniter Users Guide**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html), I'm left wondering what calling `if( !$this->upload->do_upload() )` from within the `do_upload()` method itself does.

Here's a paste of the code direclty.

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    // ** My question starts here **
        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload() ) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else{
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

As I see it, it's checking the `do_upload()` method from within `do_upload()` itself .. am I mistaken?
Forgive my naivety, but I've never seen this before .. is it a common practice?
What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( !$this->upload->do_upload() ) {
```

is calling the do_upload function which is in CI's own upload class.

The example in the docs isnt the best.

So it isnt calling do_upload within your controller again, it is calling do_upload in the upload class which does the actual uploading.

HTH

Comment: Ahhhh ... so the example class is `Upload Extends CI_Controller`, but they are _**actually**_ checking against the library upload class, which also has a `do_upload` method??? ... no wonder why I was confused :) .. it'd sure be nice if someone disambiguated that example in the docs ... thanks a bunch @Bohboh

Answer (score 1):

It's not calling itself, it calls the method `do_upload` on the `upload` property of the `Upload` controller object. The methods are simply named the same, but they belong to different objects. The `$this->upload` object seems to be the `'upload'` library which is loaded in the previous step (note: I do not know CI).